# Hosted Blazor WASM doesn't run when published to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

Trying to publish a hosted Blazor Wasm app to azure but app hangs at the loading stage. I read somewhere that the reason may be due to the Client base href tag needs to be changed to account for the way the Client is published into the wwwroot folder of the Server host. However after changing

base href="/"
to
base href="/Client/"

in the index.html it still doesn't work.

FYI, to replicate I'm using the Blazor wasm template as my test app. Command to execute is this:

*dotnet new blazorwasm -ho -o testapp*

Given that this is a pretty standard requirement I can't find any support documentation on Internet. Can anyone here offer any ideas ???

Comment: I did a test with a hosted Blazor wasm app, which work well both on local and azure. If possible, please share the structure of your project(s) and show us the detailed steps you followed to deploy your project, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: @FeiHan Thanks for your reply. Unsurprisingly this issue wasn't related to base href but something else unrelated. Thanks for assisting.